# Display Outgoing Mail Window via SmtpClient

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, outlook-2010, smtpclient

Is it possible to display the outgoing mail window in outlook using SmtpClient?
Note: Outlook is the default email client

I have a link which when clicked I want to display an outgoing mail window using SmtpClient. Is this possible?

Comment: I'm really not sure what you're asking. Outgoing Mail Window in Outlook? Like the Outbox? SmtpClient and Outlook are totally unrelated...

Comment: @Tim Not the Outbox, the window dislplayed when you initiate a new E-mail

Comment: There's no way to make a link that specifically opens up Outlook. If you have a mailto: link (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mailto) the user will be presented with the new mail window for whatever their default email client is (which may or may not be Outlook). I don't see how SmtpClient is related to that though. Are you trying to use Outlook as the editor for email that your website is sending?

Comment: @Tim Yes, Outlook is the default email client. Hence I mentioned outlook, sorry for the confusion.